# How to find composite component in JSF component tree?

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

I implement a simple method, that iterate JSF components tree and sets the components to disabled. (So the user cannot change the values). But this method doesn't function for composite components. How can I  detect a composite component at least? Then I can try to set the special attribute to disabled.

Comment: You can't detect whether something is a composite, since the only limitation on a composite component backing bean type is implementing `NamingContainer`, but there are plenty of other things implementing that interface.

Comment: Please ask one question per question. Do not chameleonize existing questions. It makes answers incomplete or even invalid.

Comment: @BalusC Sorry, but this was my first question and the idea about security comes later when I thought about this. Could you recreate your answer? Your answer was very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UIComponent` class has a [`isCompositeComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#isCompositeComponent%28javax.faces.component.UIComponent%29) helper method for exactly this purpose.

So, this should just do:

```
for (UIComponent child : component.getChildren()) {
    if (UIComponent.isCompositeComponent(child)) {
        // It's a composite child!
    }
}
```

---

For the interested in "under the covers" workings, here's the implementation source code from Mojarra 2.1.25:

```
public static boolean isCompositeComponent(UIComponent component) {

    if (component == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    boolean result = false;
    if (null != component.isCompositeComponent) {
        result = component.isCompositeComponent.booleanValue();
    } else {
        result = component.isCompositeComponent =
                (component.getAttributes().containsKey(
                           Resource.COMPONENT_RESOURCE_KEY));
    }
    return result;

}
```

It's thus identified by the presence of a component attribute with the name as definied by [`Resource.COMPONENT_RESOURCE_KEY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Resource.html#COMPONENT_RESOURCE_KEY) which has the value of [`"javax.faces.application.Resource.ComponentResource"`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.application.Resource.COMPONENT_RESOURCE_KEY).

Comment: Thank you for your help!  But now I am thinking about security issues. I have edited my question.

Comment: The link to my security question [Security issues JSF. Disabled attribute on server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274010/security-issues-jsf-disabled-attribute-on-server-side)